# How can I keep open the command prompt in my windows form application in c++?

Tags: c++, winforms, command-prompt

I wrote a project in windows form application in C++ by Visual Studio 2010. I need to open the cmd and then type special command and run other program.

I use this function :

```
system("cmd.exe /c dir c:\\");
```

but by this function I just saw cmd for a second and then it was disappeared.
then I add this line :

```
cin.get();
```

but it did not work.

also I use this function :

```
char program[] = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
WinExec((LPCSTR)program, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

but it did not work either! Can you help me please?

Comment: Explicitly casting the character array to `const char *` is absolutely pointless, and any good compiler should warn about those escape sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

`system("cmd /k dir c:\\");`

`/k` keeps the cmd prompt window open after the executing process has terminated.

But, to be honest, it may be better to use the Windows Terminal Services API for finer control, if you so desire. But, depending on what you want to do - that might be overkill.

And, regarding your second question: don't forget to escape your backslashes in:

```
const char program[] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
WinExec((LPCSTR)program, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

References:
https://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution

Comment: @GolnazSaraji: Awesome! If my answer was useful to you, please consider it for acceptance. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
cin.ignore();
```

maybe also in combination with cin.get()

```
cin.get();
cin.ignore();
```

I think normally cin.get() worked fine in my programs.

Comment: thank u for ur help .but it does not enough in case of my problem;)